# Mouseover initiates random rollover from array of elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, getelementbyid, rollover

The errors I get seem to be syntactical. I've been working on this for over 10 days and have got it functioning virtually they way that I want it to. However, what I want (ideally) is to have it so that when an element is mousedOver the function then initiates the image rollover on a different element. eg. points 1,2,3. mouseOver point1 initiates a rollover at a random selection from points 1,2 or 3. So for instance the mouse might be at 'demo1' but initiates a rollover at 'demo3'. Hopefully this makes sense. **Edit: found this page wich has similar effect except changes the background instead of the other element (eg. mouseOver square results in color/image change on circle) https://processing.org/examples/rollover.html**

The first example returns getElementById(..) null, which I think means that the variable pointed has not been defined yet (because it can't be defined until all the elements are loaded). But if it works will it also provide the effect I am hoping for?

```
<head>
<script>
//preload
window.onload = function(){
var pixel= ("black.png")
inames= ["black1.jpg", "black2.jpeg", "black3.jpg", "black4.jpg",    "black5.jpg", "black6.jpg", "black7.jpg", "black8.jpg", "black9.jpg", "black10.jpg", "black11.jpg", "black12.jpg", ,"black.png", "black13.jpg", "black14.jpg", "black15.jpg", "black16.jpg", "black17.jpg", "black18.jpg", "black19.jpg", "black20.jpg", "black21.jpg", "black22.jpg", "black23.jpg", "black.png", "black24.jpg", "black25.jpg", "black26.jpg", "black27.jpg", "black28.jpg", "black29.jpg", "black30.jpg", "black31.jpg", "black32.jpg", "black33.jpg", "black34.jpg", "black35.jpg", "black36.jpg", "black37.jpg", "black38.jpg", "black39.jpg", "black40.jpg", "black41.jpg", "black.png", "black42.jpeg", "black43.jpg", "black44.jpg", "black45.jpg", "black46.jpg", "black47.jpg", "black48.jpg", "black49.jpg", "black50.jpg", "black51.jpg", "black52.jpg", "black53.jpg", "black54.jpg", "black55.jpg", "black56.jpg", "black57.jpg", "black58.jpg"]
var selected
var myImage
var selImage
points= ["demo", "demo1", "demo2", "demo3"]
var pointed

//do not delete
document.getElementById(pointed).onmouseover = function() {mouseOver()};
document.getElementById(pointed).onmouseout = function() {mouseOut()};
document.getElementById(pointed).onmouseover = function() {mouseOver1()};
document.getElementById(pointed).onmouseout = function() {mouseOut1()};
document.getElementById(pointed).onmouseover = function() {mouseOver2()};
document.getElementById(pointed).onmouseout = function() {mouseOut2()};
document.getElementById(pointed).onmouseover = function() {mouseOver3()};
document.getElementById(pointed).onmouseout = function() {mouseOut3()};
//Random Image
function randomPick(arr) {
  var selected = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*inames.length - 1)]
  return selected;
}
//Random Element
function randomPoint(arr) {
    var pointed = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*points.length + 1)]
  return pointed;
}
//DEMO -> working
function mouseOver() {
    var myImage = document.getElementById(pointed);
    var selImage = randomPick(inames);
    myImage.src = "media/" + selImage;
}
//DEMO -> working
function mouseOut() {
    var myImage = document.getElementById(pointed);
    myImage.src = "media/black.png";
}
//DEMO1 -> working
function mouseOver1() {
    var myImage = document.getElementById(pointed);
    var selImage = randomPick(inames);
    myImage.src = "media/" + selImage;
}
//DEMO1 -> working
function mouseOut1() {
    var myImage = document.getElementById(pointed);
    myImage.src = "media/black.png";
}
//DEMO2 -> working
function mouseOver2() {
    var myImage = document.getElementById(pointed);
    var selImage = randomPick(inames);
    myImage.src = "media/" + selImage;
}
//DEMO2 -> working
function mouseOut2() {
    var myImage = document.getElementById(pointed);
    myImage.src = "media/black.png";
}
//DEMO3 -> working
function mouseOver3() {
    var myImage = document.getElementById(pointed);
    var selImage = randomPick(inames);
    myImage.src = "media/" + selImage;
}
//DEMO3 -> working
function mouseOut3() {
    var myImage = document.getElementById(pointed);
    myImage.src = "media/black.png";
}
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
```

```
<image id="demo1" src="media/black.png" style="position:absolute; top:250px; left:500px; height:auto; width:auto;" onMouseOver=mouseOver1() onmouseOut=mouseOut1() alt="image2">

<image id="demo2" src="media/black.png" style="position:absolute; top:95px; left:50px; height:auto; width:auto;" onMouseOver=mouseOver2() onmouseOut=mouseOut2() alt="image3">

<image id="demo3" src="media/black.png" style="position:absolute; top:500px; left:10px; height:auto; width:auto;" onMouseOver=mouseOver3() onmouseOut=mouseOut3() alt="image4">
</body>
```

The second example is a rather large snippet of what I have that works, that I have been trying to modify to add the randomisation to. Again, this is my first real effort at coding anything but I've been working my ass off - I wouldn't ask if I could find out how to do it myself. Any help will be much appreciated. I was searching for a more elegant and solution to create the effect that I want but due to time constraints have just decided to do it however works..

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
//preload
window.onload = function(){
var pixel= ("black.png")
inames= ["black1.jpg", "black2.jpeg", "black3.jpg", "black4.jpg", "black5.jpg", "black6.jpg", "black7.jpg", "black8.jpg", "black9.jpg", "black10.jpg", "black11.jpg", "black12.jpg", ,"black.png", "black13.jpg", "black14.jpg", "black15.jpg", "black16.jpg", "black17.jpg", "black18.jpg", "black19.jpg", "black20.jpg", "black21.jpg", "black22.jpg", "black23.jpg", "black.png", "black24.jpg", "black25.jpg", "black26.jpg", "black27.jpg", "black28.jpg", "black29.jpg", "black30.jpg", "black31.jpg", "black32.jpg", "black33.jpg", "black34.jpg", "black35.jpg", "black36.jpg", "black37.jpg", "black38.jpg", "black39.jpg", "black40.jpg", "black41.jpg", "black.png", "black42.jpeg", "black43.jpg", "black44.jpg", "black45.jpg", "black46.jpg", "black47.jpg", "black48.jpg", "black49.jpg", "black50.jpg", "black51.jpg", "black52.jpg", "black53.jpg", "black54.jpg", "black55.jpg", "black56.jpg", "black57.jpg", "black58.jpg"]
var selected
var myImage
var selImage

//do not delete
document.getElementById("demo").onmouseover = function() {mouseOver()};
document.getElementById("demo").onmouseout = function() {mouseOut()};
document.getElementById("demo1").onmouseover = function() {mouseOver1()};
document.getElementById("demo1").onmouseout = function() {mouseOut1()};
document.getElementById("demo2").onmouseover = function() {mouseOver2()};
document.getElementById("demo2").onmouseout = function() {mouseOut2()};
document.getElementById("demo3").onmouseover = function() {mouseOver3()};
document.getElementById("demo3").onmouseout = function() {mouseOut3()};

//Random Image
    function randomPick(arr) {
      var selected = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*inames.length + 1)]
      return selected;
    }
//DEMO -> working
    function mouseOver() {
        var myImage = document.getElementById(pointed);
        var selImage = randomPick(inames);
        myImage.src = "media/" + selImage;
}
//DEMO -> working
    function mouseOut() {
        var myImage = document.getElementById(pointed);
        myImage.src = "media/black.png";
    }
//DEMO1 -> working
    function mouseOver1() {
        var myImage = document.getElementById("demo1");
        var selImage = randomPick(inames);
        myImage.src = "media/" + selImage;
}
//DEMO1 -> working
    function mouseOut1() {
        var myImage = document.getElementById("demo1");
    myImage.src = "media/black.png";
}
//DEMO2 -> working
    function mouseOver2() {
        var myImage = document.getElementById("demo2");
        var selImage = randomPick(inames);
        myImage.src = "media/" + selImage;
    }
//DEMO2 -> working
    function mouseOut2() {
    var myImage = document.getElementById("demo2");
    myImage.src = "media/black.png";
}
//DEMO3 -> working
    function mouseOver3() {
    var myImage = document.getElementById("demo3");
        var selImage = randomPick(inames);
        myImage.src = "media/" + selImage;
}
//DEMO3 -> working
    function mouseOut3() {
        var myImage = document.getElementById("demo3");
    myImage.src = "media/black.png";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<image id="demo" src="media/black.png" style="position:absolute; top:35px; left:200px; height:auto; width:auto;" onMouseOver=mouseOver()  onmouseOut=mouseOut() alt="image1">

<image id="demo1" src="media/black.png" style="position:absolute; top:250px; left:500px; height:auto; width:auto;" onMouseOver=mouseOver1() onmouseOut=mouseOut1() alt="image2">

<image id="demo2" src="media/black.png" style="position:absolute; top:95px; left:50px; height:auto; width:auto;" onMouseOver=mouseOver2() onmouseOut=mouseOut2() alt="image3">

<image id="demo3" src="media/black.png" style="position:absolute; top:500px; left:10px; height:auto; width:auto;" onMouseOver=mouseOver3() onmouseOut=mouseOut3() alt="image4">
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make all of the items call a new function.  In the new function, generate a random number between 1 and 3.  Now check the value.  If the value is 1, call the first function.  If 2, call the second.  Etc.

```
function mouseOverAny(){

  var numberBetweenOneAndThree = (Math.random()*2)+1;
  switch(expression) {
    case 1:
      mouseOver1();
      break;
    case 2:
      mouseOver2();
      break;
    case 3:
      mouseOver3();
      break;
  }

}
```

...

```
<image id="demo1" src="media/black.png" style="position:absolute; top:250px; left:500px; height:auto; width:auto;" onMouseOver=mouseOverAny() onmouseOut=mouseOut1() alt="image2">
```

Comment: Beautiful answer! Being a noob it took me an hour or two to learn about it and get it working but it works fantastic! (Especially when I have 20 different elements that I want to randomise between) - thank you

Comment: Such a beautiful answer I even used it for **mouseOutAny** with **for (i=0; i <5; i++)** above **var** :)

Comment: Very nice!  Glad to help.  Don't forget to mark my answer as "correct".  :)

Comment: I've now also used it with **function rollAudio3(){audio3.play(); }** to add audio to the page - when it's finished I'll post you a link if you're interested in seeing :)

Comment: http://www.writing-spaces.com/index.htm is the link for the site - I just got it uploaded about 10 minutes ago so it's not working perfectly (eg. you can only access it if you specify .com/**index.htm** haha) but it works. Some of the images contain scenes of a graphic nature - just a heads up, there is a warning before you go into it but it shouldn't be any worse than we see on the news and they all came from good ol' doctor Google lol.

Comment: Thanks for the warning.  I'll check it out when I get home from work!